# Update the zsh autocorrection for commands

Tags: command-line, zsh

I use zsh and it's great. But the autocorrection is not smart at all. I think it is not updated at any time. So I get the following often:

```
dennis@ponyboy ~ % sudo aptitude search zsh
zsh: correct 'aptitude' to '.aptitude' [nyae]?
```

`nyae` is nothing like "forever" or "never". I am gone insane.

Okay. Autocorrection is cool. But how do I update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run

```
rehash
```

to empty zsh's command hash table

Comment: Yeah! Works pretty good!